# Why does the Google Maps server need access to a KML layer added in a client browser?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some personal kml files that I do not want to make public. I have written a web page to show them on a Google map as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml). This works as long as I keep the page public, however if I limit access, eg, by IP address, then creating and adding the layer fails, and I can see a 403 in my web logs from a Google IP address. I would have assumed that all the work was done in the client browser, why does the Google server need access to the kml file? If I do restrict access by IP address then I can allow Google's IP address, but if I choose another way to restrict access is there a way I can work around Google's server's need to access the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) renders the KML onto tiles on Google's servers, not the client (that just renders the tiles provided by the server).

If you don't want the KML sent to Google's servers you can use a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)) that renders the KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects.  There will be performance issues for complex KML.